# How to solve this convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Can anyone shed a light on this problem?

> Let $$f(x) = x^t A x + b^t x + c$$ in which $A \in \mathbb R^{nxn}$ is symmetric and positive definite, $b \in \mathbb R^n$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two parallel straight lines in $\mathbb R^n$ and $d$ be their direction vector. Let $x^1$ and $x^2$ be the minimizer of $f$ in $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively. Prove that $$(x^2 - x^1)Ad = 0$$

This problem is in the section on exact line search, steepest descent, and Newton method.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Ok José, I'll follow your advise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = f(x+td)$, then
$\phi'(t) = 2x^TAd+2t d^TAd+ b^T d$.

In particular, $\phi'(t) = 2(x+td)^T Ad + b^T d$ and if $t$ is a minimiser and $y=x+td$, we have
$2 y^T Ad + b^T d = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks! It helps me.
I did $x_1 = \widetilde{x} + \alpha d$ and $x_2 = \overline{x} + \beta d$. So:
$\phi^\prime (\alpha) = ( \widetilde{x} + \alpha d)^T Ad + b^Td = 0 $ and
$\phi^\prime (\beta) = ( \overline{x} + \beta d)^T Ad + b^Td = 0$
Then, $\phi^\prime (\beta) - \phi^\prime (\alpha) = 0$ gives the answer.